# Add a line of code to ALL functions

Tags: javascript, class, coffeescript

So I am working in JS a lot, and I am working a lot with events (try to stay as modular as possible). Current I am calling `Event.fire('eventName')` at the end of every function. I am looking for a way to have ANY function in my object/class automatically call an `Event.fire([function name])` at the end of all functions

Example:

```
function MyClass(){
   this.on('someFunc', this.funcTwo);
   this.someFunc();
}
MyClass.prototype.on = function( event ){
   // the event stuff //
}
MyClass.prototype.someFunc = function(){
   console.log('someFunc');
}
MyClass.prototype.funcTwo = function(){
   console.log('funcTwo');
}
```

Comment: You'd have to modify the Coffeescript compiler to do this, I think. It's non-trivial, because functions can have `return` statements in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this, dynamically modifying your functions:

```
var obj = MyClass.prototype;
for (var prop in obj)
    if (typeof obj[prop] == "function") // maybe also prop != "on" and similar
        (function(name, old) {
            obj[prop] = function() {
                var res = old.apply(this, arguments);
                Event.fire(name);
                return res;
            };
        })(prop, obj[prop]);
```

Comment: Trying this now, its working great. Is there any way to have this as a super class, and my other classes inherit this? So I dont have to do this for all my class/objects ? Thanks!

Comment: No. You have to execute this explicitly after you assigned the methods to your prototype objects, for each single class (wrap it in a function). Btw, if you're using inheritance, you might add a `hasOwnProperty` check as well.

Comment: Ended up using this option, Created a github repo with the code incaes anyone is looking to do this: https://github.com/qrpike/JS-Eventted-Extender

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that builds functions which always have that functionality:

```
var eventFunctionFactory = function(fn, e) {
  if (typeof fn != 'function' || typeof e != 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('Invalid function!');
  }

  return function(/* arguments */) {
    // Convert arguments to array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    // Fire event
    Event.fire(e);

    // Call the function with the applied arguments
    // Return its result
    return fn.apply(fn, args);
  };
};

var myClass = function() {
  this.someFunction = eventFunctionFactory(
                        // Function
                        function(a, b) {
                          return a + b;
                        },

                        // Event
                        function() {
                          console.log('someFunction fired!');
                        }
                      );
};

var myObj = new myClass();

// Outputs:
// someFunction fired!
// 3
console.log(myObj.someFunction(1, 2));
```

Comment: My answer is essentially the same as @Bergi's; however his transforms your functions automatically, whereas with mine, you do this explicitly.

Comment: Yet, you don't need to `slice` the `arguments`, the event should fire *after* the function and the OP's `Event.fire` seems to take a string, not a function parameter.

Comment: Fair points :) Isn't `slice` needed on the arguments for older browsers without array generics?

Comment: Only if you need it as an array - but `apply` takes pure `Arguments` objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to have a proxy class. assuming your regular class is class A and the proxy class is class B. Class B has an instance of class A internally. class B also has a stub for each Class A function that calls its internal class a instance. Then, you can add any code you want to the original class by simply adding code to the associated stub - before or after the function call to class A.

To be able to use the enhanced class, all you need to do is modify the rest of your app to instantiate class B instead of class A. The advantage with this method is your original class remains intact.

Comment: @QuintonPike: It would look a bit like my solution, only that you write to a new class' prototype instead of overwriting everything.