# How do I append a javascript-function to another javascript-function?

Tags: javascript, function, events, listener

How can I define, that a javascript function is to be called, whenever another specific javascript function has been called and executed?

```
var UploadStatusController= {
var uploadedcount,

    UpdateStatus: function (numberOfUploadedFiles) {
     UploadStatusController.uploadedcount += numberOfUploadedFiles;
    });
},


var DisplayController{
UpdateInfoBox: function () {
      $('#Infobox').InnerHtml = UploadStatusController.uploadedcount;

    });
}
```

I do not want to call my DisplayController from the UploadStatusController,
and I also do not want to pass my DisplayController into the UploadStatusController as a variable.
Instead, I am looking for a way to bind my function to calls on the other function in a way similar to binding it to a document-event.

Comment: Read about *aspect-orientated programming* and the *decorator pattern*. See possible implementation at [Add a line of code to ALL functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618309/add-a-line-of-code-to-all-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var uploadStatusController = {};
(function () {
    var subscribers = [];

    var uploadedCount = 0;

    uploadStatusController.updateStatus = function (numberOfUploadedFiles) {
        uploadedCount += numberOfUploadedFiles;

        // call subscribers
        callSubscribers();
    };

    uploadStatusController.subscribe = function (fn) {
        subscribers.push(fn);
    };
    function callSubscribers() {
        for (var i = 0, len = subscribers.length; i < len; i++) {
            subscribers[i].apply(this, [uploadedCount]);
        }
    };
}());

// subscribe to event from anywhere you need
uploadStatusController.subscribe(function (uploadedCount) {
    console.log(uploadedCount);
});
```

Comment: I thought of something like this as well, except I would have passed the controller instead of the function. I like yours better. Both approaches have one drawback: They do not scale. Whenever you want to use this pattern, a controller needs to be extended with some functions and variables.