# Extend prototype with another prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, extend

How can I extend prototype A with prototype B, so whenever I call prototype A, both will be executed?

```
var Helper = function() {

}
Helper.prototype.resizer = function() {   
  $('body').append(' Window resized ');
}

var Something = function() {
  // Extend Helper.resizer with Something.anything
  // extend(Helper.resizer, this.anything);
}
Something.prototype.anything = function() {   
  $('body').append(' Run this on resize to ');
}

var help = new Helper();
var some = new Something();

$(window).on("resize", function(){
  help.resizer();
});
```

Made an example at codepen:
http://codepen.io/robbue/pen/892c8f61e1b5a970d6f694a59db401a6
jQuery allowed, or just vanilla.

Comment: Why not just add `some.anything();` to the resize event handler?

Comment: You should be more concise about what you want. When `help.resizer()` is called, on which element do you want `anything()` to be executed? On `some`? But always, or only when the caller is `help`?

Comment: Something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/6fsub/1/ ???

Comment: I don't want the `some.anything()` in the resize event, because `some.anything()` won't run always, only when I choose to extend it to the resize event.

It should only run when the caller is help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a line of code to ALL functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618309/add-a-line-of-code-to-all-functions)

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your question because *prototypes* are not *executed*, but I think you want something like this:

```
var Helper = function() {}
Helper.prototype.resizer = function() {   
  $('body').append(' Window resized ');
}

var Something = function(h) {
  var oldresizer = h.resizer,
      that = this;
  h.resizer = function() {
      var res = oldresizer.apply(this, arguments);
      that.anything();
      return res;
  };
}
Something.prototype.anything = function() {   
  $('body').append(' Run this on resize to ');
}

var help = new Helper();
new Something(help);

$(window).on("resize", function(){
  help.resizer();
});
```

or that:

```
function Helper() {}
Helper.prototype.resizer = function() {   
  $('body').append(' Window resized ');
}

function Something() { // inherits Helper
  Helper.apply(this, arguments);
}
Something.prototype = Object.create(Helper.prototype);
Something.prototype.anything = function() {   
  $('body').append(' Run this on resize to ');
};
Something.prototype.resizer = function() {
  Helper.prototype.resizer.call(this);
  this.anything();
};

var help = new Something(help);

$(window).on("resize", function(){
  help.resizer();
});
```