# PhantomJS callback/hook Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to create a PhantomJS script that evaluates the entire page with all of its Javascripts but calls my callback every time when a specific function is called (Say, all accesses to function myGoodFunc()) and counts them.

Anybody knows a way to do so?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a line of code to ALL functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618309/add-a-line-of-code-to-all-functions)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a really dirty way:

In your phantomjs script, you can do

```
for (i=0;document.getElementsByTagName('script');;i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('script').innerText.replace(/'functionname()'/g, /'callback(), functionname()'/);
}
```

This will cause a syntax error if a method acts right away on the output of a function, eg `Object.functionname().length` will become `Object.functionname(), callback().length` which will product some kind of error.

But, this could be a nice start. As for counting the occurences of calls to this function, you could just create a global variable in your callback function and do `count++` at the end of that function.

Actually, just thought of this, a second approach would be to modify the function definition; so if there is a function literal `var functionName = function () {`, just repace it in a similar fashion with:

```
var functionName = function() { \n callback();
```

Have fun!